# Using BigQueryInsertJobOperator instead of BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Recently updated my Airflow and saw `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` has been deprecated in favor of `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`. The documentation seemed rather vague, linking to [REST Resource: jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs) (and [Method: jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest)). In particular, it's unclear to me whether there's anywhere I can specify `write_disposition`, `destination_dataset_table`, etc. I want to make sure I'm not making things overly complicated.

Where I currently do

```
# my.sql
SELECT * FROM `proj.ds.table_1`
---------------------------------
# my-dag.py
BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id='copy-table-1',
    sql = 'my.sql',
    destination_dataset_table='proj:ds.table_2',
    write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY',
    dag=dag
)
```

do I now need to use [DDL statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) like

```
# my.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
ds.table_2
AS (
  SELECT * FROM `proj.ds.table_1`
)
---------------------------------
# my-dag.py
BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='copy-table-1',
    configuration={
        'query': my.sql
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Not to mention passing parameters to the query in the format suggested by the [QueryParameter docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryParameter) instead of just `params={ 'table': THE_TABLE }`...

Comment: I'm also having some issues understanding the new Operator but I asked in the Airflow channel and they pointed me to the example dag that shows this: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/25caeda58b50eae6ef425a52e794504bc63855d1/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags

Comment: Google API is not a low hanging fruit. Hope the following would be of any help:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfiguration
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery

Answer (score 8):

This is the API documentation to follow for the `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery.

Rather than mess with Google's parameterized SQL queries, I'm using this method to get templated queries to write to BQ:

```
# my.sql
SELECT * FROM `{PROJECT}.{DATASET}.{TBL_TO_MOVE}`
---------------------------------
# my-dag.py
PROJECT = 'my-project'
DATASET = 'my-dataset'
TBL_TO_MOVE = 'some-table'

DESTINATION_DS = 'other-dataset'
DESTINATION_TBL = 'other-table'

BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='copy-table-1',
    configuration={
        'query': {
            'query': open('my.sql', 'r').read().format(**locals()),
            'destinationTable': {
                'projectId': PROJECT,
                'datasetId': DESTINATION_DS,
                'tableId': DESTINATION_TBL
            },
            'useLegacySql': False,
            'allowLargeResults': True,
        }
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

The `open('my.sql', ...)` reads the SQL file then uses local variables in place of the brace variables (e.g. `{PROJECT}` gets replaced by `my-project`).

Answer (score 3):

I used the same method that @zack did. However, I used the jinja format for finding the SQL file.

`"query": "{% include 'path/to/file.sql' %}"`

Answer (score 1):

To add more to the conversation, adding a query as a file is even easier

```
BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='create_table',
    configuration={
        'query': {
            'query': 'path/to/file.sql',
            'useLegacySql': False,
        }
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition here's the Airflow documentation on examples of `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#howto-operator-bigqueryinsertjoboperator