# How can i do a Load Job in BQ using Airflow BigQueryInsertJobOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

In Airflow, I want to use the new `BigQueryInsertJobOperator()` instead of the deprecated `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator()` to do a LOAD job.

So I want to load files from Google Cloud Storage to BQ.

The documentation seems limited or somewhat confusing.

I have found this question, but it is more about a BigQuery query job and not a load job:
[Using BigQueryInsertJobOperator instead of BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66895314/using-bigqueryinsertjoboperator-instead-of-bigqueryexecutequeryoperator/77415525)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an **example setup** that uses the configuration for load jobs from GCS to BQ using Airflow `BigQueryInsertJobOperator()`:

```py
load_job_config = {
    "jobType": "LOAD",
    "load": {
        "sourceUris": [
            "gs://location_of_your_files/*.csv"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "some id field",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "REQUIRED",
                },
                {
                    "name": "some other string field",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "REQUIRED",
                },
            ]
        },
        "destinationTable": {
            "projectId": "your project name",
            "datasetId": "your dataset name",
            "tableId": "your table name",
        },
        "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        "fieldDelimiter": "\t",
        "sourceFormat": "CSV",
    },
}

load_gcs_files_into_bigquery = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="load_gcs_files_into_bigquery",
    configuration=load_job_config,
)
```

**However** I find this dictionary style quite verbose, so you can also do it as if it is a query (instead of a load job):

```py
QUERY_LOAD_GCS_INTO_BQ = """
    LOAD DATA OVERWRITE `project_id.dataset_name.table_name` (
      some_id_field STRING, 
      some_other_field STRING,
    )
    FROM FILES (
      format = 'CSV',
      field_delimiter = '\t',
      uris = ['gs://location_of_your_files/*.csv']
    )
"""

load_gcs_into_bigquery = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="load_gcs_into_bigquery",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": QUERY_LOAD_GCS_INTO_BQ,
            "useLegacySql": False,
        }
    },
)
```

More configuration options can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfiguration

Some simple examples can be found here too:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#execute-bigquery-jobs